# Convert JSON values datatype from into to string

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am currently writing an api response and the requirement is that all integers must inside double quotes. 
Ex:

```
{
"Key1": {"SubKey1":"1", "SubKey2":"2"},
"Key2": "2"
}
```

When I use json.dumps() to convert my dict to json str I'm getting this result:

```
{
"Key1": {"SubKey1":1, "SubKey2":2},
"Key2":2
}
```

(the values of keys are int objects in python).
What should I do to make the values appear inside quotes?

I have tried casting them by using

```
string_ver = {str(key): str(d[key]) for key in d}
```

but this did not convert the values for subkey into strings (as expected)

Comment: You should cast them to strings before dumping them to JSON.

Comment: Like this new_d = {str(key): str(value) for key, value in keys_values} @robinsax

Comment: That will work on your provided sample, yep.

Comment: @robinsax I edited my question to be more precise, my proposed solution did not work for this sample case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, the reason you're getting answers that don't work is you didn't supply a good piece of sample data. You should make sure your sample input always matches the shape of your true input when posting.

That being said, recursion is your friend here. The following function will return a copy the provided dict with all values cast to string, handling an arbitrary nesting depth. If `data` contains lists, further modification will be required.

```py
def cast_values_to_str(data):
    result = dict()
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            result[key] = cast_values_to_str(value)
        else:
            result[key] = str(value)
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:
You have to convert recursively each `int` to strings:

```
def convert_simple_dct(dct):
    for key, val in dct.items():
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            dct[key] = convert_simple_dct(val)
        else:
            dct[key] = str(val)
    return dct

dct = {
    "Key1": {"SubKey1":1, "SubKey2":2},
    "Key2": 2
}
print(json.dumps(convert_simple_dct(dct)))
```

Comment: I edited my question to be more precise: the python object would be 
mydict = {
"Key1": {"SubKey1":1, "SubKey2":2},
"Key2":2
}

Sorry for the confusion

Comment: OK, then here you go ;)

Answer (score 0):

Integers in your Python dictionary will be represented as integers in the JSON. If you want them to be strings, convert them to strings in Python:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({'thing': str(2)})
'{"thing": "2"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce, when I run this code:

```
In [1]: import json                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
In [2]: mydict= {"Key1": "1", "Key2": "2"}                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
In [3]: json.dumps(mydict)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[3]: '{"Key1": "1", "Key2": "2"}'
```

Comment: I edited my question to be more precise: the python object would be 
mydict = {
"Key1": {"SubKey1":1, "SubKey2":2},
"Key2":2
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to @pyOliv and @robinsax, I found the solution to it.

```
def recursive_change_int_to_string(dictObj):
for key, val in dictObj.items():
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        recursive_change_int_to_string(val)
    elif isinstance(val, int):
        dictObj[key] = str(val)
```

and then

```
sampleDict = {"Key1": {"SubKey1":1, "SubKey2":2}, "Key2":2 }

recursive_change_int_to_string(sampleDict)

json.dumps(sampleDict )
```

gave me:

```
{
"Key1": {"SubKey1":"1", "SubKey2":"2"},
"Key2": "2"
}
```